# How to connect Twilio SIP Domain to a twilio studio flow?

Tags: twilio, sip

On Twilio I configured a Sip Domain and I created a flow in Twilio Studio. I want to connect them so when I call the number registered in the SIP Domain I want the call connected to the flow in Twilio Studio.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio staff here. You should be able to do this using your Studio Flow's webhook URL.

To find the webhook for your flow, click on the flow's trigger:

[image: image of studio flow trigger]

Then copy and paste the webhook URL into your SIP domain's voice configuration:

[image: image of SIP domain config page]

Click "Save" at the bottom of the SIP domain configuration page and incoming calls will trigger your Studio Flow.

Comment: I just spent an evening trying to figure this out, and it wasn't working the way you describe. In testing, I haven't been able to get calls to the domain to invoke any webhook, whether for a studio flow or a function -- the call just goes directly to the registered endpoint. I was testing this with a tiny TwiML App pointing to a Bin that dials the SIP endpoint. Is there any reason this would expect to bypass the Domain's webhook?

Comment: Actually I just figured this out -- the webhook (and studio flow) was invoked when I made an OUTBOUND call from an endpoint on the SIP domain. Is it possible to do this in reverse?

Comment: how about the other way around, i.e. a call to be be connected to the  sip domain